# How can I tie an array slice to the original array so all changes that are made to one are made to both?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, slice

I need to be able to tie an array slice to the original array in such a way that any changes made to the original array (including removing elements) will also be made to the array slice.  Is there a way to do this?

---

The following example **does not work** how I want it to, but it is simply there to demonstrate the point I am trying to make.

**Example:**

```
my @array = 1 .. 10;
my @slice = @array[3 .. 8];

splice @array, 5, 2;

print "ARRAY: ";
print join ', ', @array;
print "\n";

print "SLICE: ";
print join ', ', @slice;
```

**Output:**

```
ARRAY: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10
SLICE: 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

---

What I am looking for is a way to tie the slice to the original array so the output would look like this instead:

```
ARRAY: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10
SLICE: 4, 5, 8, 9
```

***Removing 6 and 7 from the original array would also remove it from the array slice.***

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I'm working on a script that is handling a hierarchical database structure and I want each record to hold an array of its child records.  If one of the records that is referenced in the list of child records is deleted from the whole database, I want the array of child records to be automatically updated to remove the record.

Comment: Basically the database has a big array of all of the records and the child record array would be a slice of the big array.  If a record is removed from the big array I want it removed from any slices it is referenced in as well.

Comment: Ah okay, so similar to foreign keys and ON DELETE CASCADE in relational databases. I know you try to avoid putting background info like that in your questions, but in this case I think it would be very helpful to include it; XY problem and what not.

Comment: There are various aliasing modules on CPAN. But this is a tall order as you're asking for an array to be aliased to an array slice. You're asking for index translation effectively. I suggest that it may be easier if you keep your overarching array of data, and deal with arrays of *indexes* into the data. It should be easy to write a class consisting of a range of indexes and a number of child objects of the same class that behave just as you describe. But a lot depends on what operations you need to perform on this data.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: ThisSuitIsBlackNot is quite right. The answer to your question is probably a "no", but you have happened upon an unworkable approach.

Comment: @Borodin, is there anywhere I can find a very basic example of what you are describing?  I feel like that is probably the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, It is possible. `@array` would have to be magical, and `@slice` would have to be magical or a reference. It would take alot of code, and it would break down very easily. Far better to make an OO interface instead.

Comment: @ikegami, I'll look into finding an OO approach ...but magic is what makes Perl great! :)

Comment: I'm not referring to magic in the general sense, but that which is added by `sv_magic`. Variable::Magic provides a Perl-land interface to this.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: I'm afraid there isn't an example that I know of, and there's unlikely to be one as it's not a common problem. Start by writing a class that contains an array of indexes and an array of child objects. Then define all the operations that you want to perform on your objects and write them as methods. `splice`, for instance, involves just splicing the array of indexes and then performing an appropriate splice on each child object that covers the indexes just removed (or part of it). Each child will cascade the operation automatically by doing the same to its children in turn.

Comment: @ikegami, That's interesting, I've never heard of `sv_magic` before. I don't mean to waste your time, but I am really interested in seeing a "magical" solution to this problem as well as an OO approach.  If you have the time it would be very cool to see, if not don't worry about it. :)

Comment: @Borodin, I will give that a try, thank you.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: Be careful what you wish for! I suggest you take a look at the [Variable::Magic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Variable::Magic) module and think about whether you could understand such a solution first. IMO it's little more than an interesting toy.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, It's what powers `$!`, `%ENV`, `%SIG`, etc, variables that act as functions calls. And no, it would take too long to write. A slice can be defined as a starting index and a length/ending index. Inserting/removing from the array would have to update the definition of the splice. That means that each array that's been spliced would need to keep of list of all existing splices of the array.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, You can already create a view of a segment of a string, but it's not quite what you want: `perl -E'my $array = join("", map chr, 1..12); my $slice_ref = \substr($array, 3, 8-3+1); substr($array, 5, 2, ""); say for unpack "C*", $array; say for unpack "C*", $$slice_ref;'` (Magic is used here. Specifically, the value returned by substr in lvalue context is magical.)

Comment: I correct what I said earlier: You can't quite do what you want because you would need to use a special function instead of `splice`.  It would add magic to the original array, and it would return a reference to an array (the slice), which would also be magical.

Comment: @ikegami, Okay I will look into an example of that and see if it helps.

Comment: Do it using objects first. You need to write all that code anyway!

Comment: Haha okay, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, that's a tall order.  The short answer is no.  A slice creates a copy of the elements.

Perl does have a Tie feature that might be just the trick.

```
perltie - how to hide an object class in a simple variable
```

So it fundamentally changes what a variable is behind the scenes.  A whole world of possibilities opens up, and your scenario just might be in there.

[perltie on perldoc.perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html)

Answer (score 1):

Updated post as requested using Object oriented method.  Maintained original response after <========> Line

Here's the object oriented approach as mentioned in comments.
Sample.pm

```
package Sample;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);
use List::MoreUtils qw(first_index);
our @y = qw (3 4 5 6 7 8 9); # Add your method of acquiring @y value here
our @EXPORT = qw (SpliceV2 @y);

##  Your Splice Version 2

sub SpliceV2(@) {
my ($position,$length,@x) = @_;
for (my $i=1;$i<=$length;$i++) {
my $removeditem = $x[$position];
my $remove = first_index { $_ eq $removeditem } @y;
splice @x, $position, 1;
splice @y, $remove, 1;
}

return @x;
}

1;
```

Main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Sample;
my @x = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10);

@x = SpliceV2(4,2,@x);
print "X: @x\n";
print "Y: @y\n";
```

Original post below
<==========>
Assuming the items you are removing are unique like if you are basing it on primary keys of a database, then you can use first_index from List::MoreUtils;

Here's a sample.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(first_index);
my @x = qw (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10);
my @y = qw (4 5 6 7 8 9);

## Let's say you want to remove 2 items after the 5th index

my $position = 5;
my $length = 2;

##      Get the value of items to remove first

for (my $i=1;$i<=$length;$i++) {
  my $removeditem = $x[$position];
  my $remove = first_index { $_ eq $removeditem } @y;
  splice @x, $position, 1;
  splice @y, $remove, 1;
}
print "Array X\n";
print "$_," foreach(@x);
print "\nArray Y\n";
print "$_," foreach(@y);
print "\n";
```

You should get the result you wanted.

```
Array X
1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,
Array Y
4,5,8,9,
```

Comment: While this does provide the desired output, it does not "tie" the array to the slice. By "tie" I mean make it so any action performed on the array will implicitly also be performed on the slice without having to duplicate that action separately on the slice. If they were "tied" then `splice @x, $position, 1;` would also act on `@y` so the second `splice` would not be necessary.

Comment: You just need to create a class using the mentioned the above method. Then It will technically tie both your arrays together. Like call it spliceV2 for example. spliceV2(5,2,@x); would then give you the result you want given you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you mean. I don't see clearly how that could be put into a class to make spliceV2 work. Can you elaborate or update the answer to show?

Comment: I have added the object oriented version for SpliceV2. Try it on your machine :-)

Answer (score -3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @array = 1..10;
my @slice = \@array[3..8];

splice @array, 5, 2;

print "ARRAY: ";
print join ', ', @array;
print "\n";

print "SLICE: ";
print join ', ', @slice;
```

Output:

```
ARRAY: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10
SLICE: SCALAR(0x29dcef0), SCALAR(0x29dcf20), SCALAR(0x29dcf08), SCALAR(0x29dcfb0), SCALAR(0x29dcfc, SCALAR(0x29dd058)
```

Instead removing the items you could assign a zero value to the item (it will assign a zero value in the `@slice` too, because `@slice` holds a refference to `@array`) and then remove the 0's from you `@slice` and voila, you have your updated `@slice` with your deleted elements

Comment: This doesn't work. Adding `splice @array, 5, 2; print join ', ', @slice;` does not produce the expected output (and neither does `splice @array, 5, 2; print join ', ', map $$_, @slice;`)

Comment: Did you use my code? Explain "does not reproduce the EXPECTED output"

Comment: If you READ the whole answer you will see that I actually provided a "workarround" for removed elements.

Comment: Then why do you use the `splice`? Does it create references to your `@array`?

Comment: The OP wants `splice @array` to modify both `@array` and `@slice`. If he just wanted to alias elements, `my $slice = sub { \@_ }->(@array[3..8]);` would be a better job

Comment: Re "*I don't see that in the OP's question*", Obviously. That's why I pointed it out and downvoted your answer. /// Re "*And you might consider using a Data::Dumper to see the results*" That code should output `ARRAY: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10
SLICE: 4, 5, 8, 9`. Even changing `print join ', ', @slice;` to `print join ', ', map $$_, @slice;` doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, I understood now. Thanks for the explanations.